# How to capture key press events in Windows Form application without adding focus?

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2012

I'm new to C# and programming, so this may seem simple, but I've looked hard for help.

I'm trying to implement WASD controls on an object in Visual Studio 2012 (specifically, an ellipse) I understand how to manipulate the object - my problem is collecting user input.

It seems like in the past, people used `System.Windows.Forms`, but I'm not sure that's around any more (it says there is a missing token, and when I go to add references, it says all are added).

I tried adding a key down event to the grid, but it never triggers. I can't set Focus to the grid, because that was in `System.Windows.Forms`.

So my question: Any tips on how to implement WASD controls? or more, specifically, how can I register when the user presses a key WITHOUT manually adding focus to an object?

Comment: what project type did you create?

Comment: Blank, I started everything from scratch.

Comment: a blank solution? i meant like Winforms, class library, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're saying VS2012, C# but `Elipse` and no `System.Windows.Forms` I'm going to hazard a guess that you really did File -> New Project -> WPF Application (since that has an Ellipse control (primitive) off the bat).

Since `Elipse` can't get focus you'll need to decide when a key press is interesting, to do this add a handler to the Window. Here's some sample XAML:

```
  <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" KeyDown="Window_KeyDown">
    <Grid>
      <Ellipse x:Name="elipsy" Fill="#FFF4F4F5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Canvas.Left="241" Canvas.Top="119"/>
    </Grid>
  </Window>
```

In your handler (`Window_KeyDown`) you could then do:

```
    private void Window_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.W)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(elipsy, Canvas.GetTop(elipsy) - 1);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.A)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(elipsy, Canvas.GetLeft(elipsy) - 1);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.S)
        {
            Canvas.SetTop(elipsy, Canvas.GetTop(elipsy) + 1);
        }
        else if (e.Key == Key.D)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(elipsy, Canvas.GetLeft(elipsy) + 1);
        }
    }
```

This should get you started on the right track. If you really did want WinForms give a holler and we should be able to find a similar solution there.